# In-line code tag not properly displayed in chat preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

[Proof of the bug](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3058616#3058616):

[image]

I'm sorry I have no theory as to what could be the cause.

Comment: Looks like the truncation with ellipsis was applied after the string was HTML encoded, and the `&gt;` got caught in the cross-fire.

Answer (score 4):

The truncation code was not considering entities. Now it is! :-)

The fix should be applied in the next chat deployment.

Comment: If this was fixed, shouldn't it be retagged [meta-tag:status-completed]? :)