# “Community bulletin” box truncates in the middle of the HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin

The “community bulletin” box on Ask Different currently includes this text:

> How should I handle an accepted answer that's no longer “correct&rd...

resulting from the HTML

```
How should I handle an accepted answer that&#39;s no longer &ldquo;correct&rd...
```

which presumably resulted from the truncation being applied to HTML text rather than plain text.

Comment: Likely related, for linkability (in the "using the same utility method post-HTML-encoding" sense): [In-line code tag not properly displayed in chat preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126853)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix has been deployed for this issue.